Why does this assembly code not store the correct output?
i test a assembly code in kali linux but i problem with output
this my code:
**`.section .data
.equ RECORD_FIRSTNAME, 0
.equ RECORD_LASTNAME, 40
.equ RECORD_ADDRESS, 80
.equ RECORD_AGE, 320
.equ RECORD_SIZE, 324
.equ SYS_EXIT, 1
.equ SYS_READ, 3
.equ SYS_WRITE, 4
.equ SYS_OPEN, 5
.equ SYS_CLOSE, 6
.equ SYS_BRK, 45
.equ LINUX_SYSCALL, 0x80
.equ STDIN, 0
.equ STDOUT, 1
.equ STDERR, 2
.equ END_OF_FILE, 0
.equ ST_WRITE_BUFFER, 8
.equ ST_FILEDES, 12

record1:
.ascii "Fredrick\0"
.rept 31 #Padding to 40 bytes
.byte 0
.endr
.ascii "Bartlett\0"
.rept 31 #Padding to 40 bytes
.byte 0
.endr
.ascii "4242 S Prairie\nTulsa, OK 55555\0"
.rept 209 #Padding to 240 bytes
.byte 0
.endr
.long 45
record2:
.ascii "Marilyn\0"
.rept 32 #Padding to 40 bytes
.byte 0
.endr
.ascii "Taylor\0"
.rept 33 #Padding to 40 bytes
.byte 0
.endr
.ascii "2224 S Johannan St\nChicago, IL 12345\0"
.rept 203 #Padding to 240 bytes
.byte 0
.endr
.long 29
record3:
.ascii "Derrick\0"
.rept 32 #Padding to 40 bytes
.byte 0
.endr
.ascii "McIntire\0"
.rept 31 #Padding to 40 bytes
.byte 0
.endr
.ascii "500 W Oakland\nSan Diego, CA 54321\0"
.rept 206 #Padding to 240 bytes
.byte 0
.endr
.long 36
file_name:
.ascii "test.dat\0"
.equ ST_FILE_DESCRIPTOR, -4

.section .text
.globl _start
_start:
#Copy the stack pointer to %ebp
movl %esp, %ebp
#Allocate space to hold the file descriptor
subl $4, %esp
#Open the file
movl $SYS_OPEN, %eax
movl $file_name, %ebx
movl $0101, %ecx #This says to create if it
#doesn’t exist, and open for
#writing
movl $0666, %edx
int $LINUX_SYSCALL
#Store the file descriptor away
movl %eax, ST_FILE_DESCRIPTOR(%ebp)
#Write the first record
pushl ST_FILE_DESCRIPTOR(%ebp)
pushl $record1
call write_record
addl $8, %esp
#Write the second record
pushl ST_FILE_DESCRIPTOR(%ebp)
pushl $record2
call write_record
addl $8, %esp
#Write the third record
pushl ST_FILE_DESCRIPTOR(%ebp)
pushl $record3
call write_record
addl $8, %esp
#Close the file descriptor
movl $SYS_CLOSE, %eax
movl ST_FILE_DESCRIPTOR(%ebp), %ebx
int $LINUX_SYSCALL
#Exit the program
movl $SYS_EXIT, %eax
movl $0, %ebx
int $LINUX_SYSCALL


.globl write_record
.type write_record, @function
write_record:
pushl %ebp
movl %esp, %ebp
pushl %ebx
movl $SYS_WRITE, %eax
movl ST_FILEDES(%ebp), %ebx
movl ST_WRITE_BUFFER(%ebp), %ecx
movl $RECORD_SIZE, %edx
int $LINUX_SYSCALL
#NOTE - %eax has the return value, which we will
# give back to our calling program
popl %ebx
movl %ebp, %esp
popl %ebp
ret`**

This is the output that should be displayed:
Fredrick
Bartlett
4242 S Prairie
Tulsa, OK 55555
45
Marilyn
Taylor
2224 S Johannan St
Chicago, IL 12345
29
Derrick
McIntire
500 W Oakland
San Diego, CA 54321
36
But it displays the output:
Fredrick
Bartlett
4242 S Prairie
Tulsa, OK 55555
-MarMarilyn
Taylor
2224 S Johannan St
Chicago, IL 12345
DerrDerrick
McIntire
500 W Oakland
San Diego, CA 54321
$test
First, why does it not store the age, which was introduced as long
Second, why does it not follow formatting?
please help
thank you
i compile this command in linux
as --32 myapp.s -o myapp.o
ld -m elf_i386 myapp.o -o myapp
./myapp

Now is a great time to enhance your debugging skills.  Single step and observe where the program differs from your expectations.

Since you are printing the whole record at once, you include the padding zeroes. Also you do not have spaces. The age is stored as binary, it is printed accordingly. You need to convert it to text if you want the human readable form.
